# Find Records in SQL not having a particular value

Tags: sql-server

Hi All I need a help finding a query that will get all records form my table
where it does not contain a pair alarmtype where its value is 'RETURN' and another value heres my table:

```
AlarmType   Day                     PointName 
SENSOR      2017-09-02 00:00:00.000 20CHB01CE104XG95.UNIT2@NET0
RETURN      2017-09-02 00:00:00.000 20CHB01CE104XG95.UNIT2@NET0
RETURN      2017-09-02 00:00:00.000 20CHB01CE105XG95.UNIT2@NET0
SENSOR      2017-09-02 00:00:00.000 20CHB01CE105XG95.UNIT2@NET0
RETURN      2017-09-02 00:00:00.000 20CHB01CE106XG95.UNIT2@NET0
SENSOR      2017-09-02 00:00:00.000 20CHB01CE106XG95.UNIT2@NET0
RETURN      2017-09-02 00:00:00.000 20CHB01CE107XG95.UNIT2@NET0
SENSOR      2017-09-02 00:00:00.000 20CHB01CE107XG95.UNIT2@NET0

HIGH1       2017-09-02 00:00:00.000 20LBB20CP003.UNIT2@NET0

SENSOR      2017-09-02 00:00:00.000 20MAV10CL011.UNIT2@NET0
```

Now the answer I am looking for is the last 2 rows since they don't have any 'RETURN' Values

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I just need to find a way to find any matching records that does NOT have an AlarmType = 'RETURN' and another Alarmtype. so very sorry for my english it's not my first language

Comment: So you want to eliminate the SENSOR/RETURN pairs that match and see what's left? Since they all have the same timestamp, how do you know which are pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
select *
from <table>
where pointName not in (select pointName from <table> where alarmType = 'return');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE alarmtype <> 'RETURN'
```